# How to call a superclass method of Ext JS 3.4 Window

Tags: extjs, superclass

I have a window class like so:

```
    myWindow = Ext.extend(WindowAddItemUi, {

    initComponent: function() {

        WindowAddComponentPublic.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

    },

    close : function() {
        this.superclass().close(); //not working
        myWindow.superclass().close(); //also not working

    }

   });
```

I am trying to overwrite the close method of a window and call the supermethod close of the window, but it does not seem to work.
Does anyone know how to call it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

```
close: function() {
    this.callParent();
}
```

Comment: In initComponent you can use this.callParent(arguments);

Comment: @JohanHaest Yes, but if you extend the components several times and wait arguments in parent initComponent, they need to pass. This design allow not think about it.

Comment: `this.callParent();` did not work for me. I got an error _this.callParent is not a function_
For now I have fixed it with an eventlistener, but I was hoping to do it without that and just overwrite the close method of the window.

My solution: 

`this.on('close', function() {
            this.dataviewComponents1.getStore().removeAll();
            this.dataviewComponents2.getStore().removeAll();
        }, this);`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I got it working finally. 
And this is my solution that fixed it.

```
close : function() {
 this.superclass().close.call(this); //this works
 // myWindow.superclass.close.call(this); //this also works 
}
```